# Terminal input doesn't work in QNX running on VM or x86 hardware

Tags: shell, virtual-machine, virtualbox, qnx

I'm doing a university project on QNX RTOS (using an academic license). I'm following [Building a BSP](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.building/topic/bsp/bsp_build.html).

So far I've managed to build (using `bios_mkusbimage` script in the BSP archive) .img file for x86_64 target. Then I converted `.img` to `.vdi` file (`VBoxManage convertdd input.img output.vdi`) and finally loaded it. The result is: [image: vm starting output]

Or, as text:

```
Loading IFS...decompressing...done 
System page at phys:000000000010c000 user:ffff808000003000 kern 808000006000 

Starting next program at vffff80000007388b MFLAGS=1 .11 ClockCycles offsets within tolerance elcome to Q. Neutrino SDP 7.0 on x8664 system 
Starting slogger2 server ...
Starting PCI server ... 
Set PCI device list ... 
Starting EIDE block driver ... 
unable to access /dev/hd0t179 'ot3Tt11:7.n:nele7i7la:TensleieCted 
Starting USD host ... 
Starting devb-umass o audio device has been detected 
Starting input services ... 
Starting serial driver ... 
Starting consoles ... 
Starting shells ... 
#
```

The OS seems to boot successfully, but I'm unable to type anything.

I'm looking either for a way to fix the keyboard input, or get a SSH/telnet/... connection to the QNX shell.